Strange sequence of rational asymptotes from $\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$
Consider the function
$$f_1 (x) = \frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} = \left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{-1}$$

Notice that it has an "asymptote" of $y = x$: while on the plot it looks like this line would intersect $f_1(x)$ near $0$, it is in fact merely a floating point fluke. From here on I will ignore the behaviour of my functions very close to zero.
Our asymptote will have a slope of $1$. We then set $a_1 = 1$. Let's consider the next function, $f_2$:
$$f_2(x) = \left(f_1(x) - x\right)^{-1}$$

Again, ignoring the behaviour around $0$, this function also has an asymptote with slope $6$ -- a really surprising fact for me! This way, we set $a_2 = 6$.
Doing this process again, we get:
$$f_3(x) = \left(f_2(x) - 6x\right)^{-1}$$
which has an asymptote of slope $-\frac{10}{7}$.
We can rigorously define this sequence. To get the slope of an asymptote, we can take the derivative of the function and look at its behaviour at infinity. We get the following recursive expression
$$f_{n+1}(x) = (f_{n}(x) - a_{n} x)^{-1}$$
where
$$a_{n} = \lim_{x\to\infty} f_{n}'(x)$$
Using some short sympy code I was able to extract more terms of $a_n = \frac{p}{q}$:
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & p & q & \approx \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 6 & 1 & 6\\ \hline
3 & -10 & 7 & -1.4285714285714286 \\ \hline
4 & -686 & 11 & -62.36363636363637 \\ \hline
5 & 2178 & 3857 & 0.5646875810215193  \\ \hline
6 & 607202 & 1331 & 456.1998497370398 \\ \hline
7 & -46060586 & 264066199 & -0.1744281781402852 \\ \hline
8 & -6890388120030 & 2354497739 & -2926.4789708213857 \\ \hline
9 & 106394544980674 & 2197798747760801 & 0.0484095939580786\\ \hline
10 &799166018913201988838 & 45643180290397441 & 17508.990693212785\\ \hline
\end{array}$
The 10th term took almost 40 minutes to calculate and I did not have time to calculate more of them. However, from the patterns I see so far, I can predict that:

The 11th and 12th terms will both be negative
The 11th term will be "small" in absolute value and the 12th term will be "big" in absolute value. I am still not quite sure how to quantify the size of these terms, though.

My guess is that these terms may be related to the series expansion of $f_1(x)$ at $x=\infty$, which WolframAlpha gives to be:

These agree up to the first two terms. Perhaps there is a way to from one to the other?
My question is: does whatever I am doing have a name? Does this sequence represent anything? Can I do this with functions other than $\sin(1/x)$? Why are the terms necessarily rational?
Updates:

I performed the same transformation but instead considered
$$g_1(x) = \left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{-1}$$
The result was really surprising: $a_n = (-1)^{n-1} (2n-1)$ (so basically odd numbers with alternating signs). I instantly associated with the Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$, which displays the same behaviour but in the denominators. Unfortunately, the series for $\arcsin(x)$ looks completely unrelated to mine and I was unable to see any connection between the two.
I also tried considering $f_1 (x) = \left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x
^k}\right)\right)^{-1}$, for $k\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and I see that the same sequence $a_n$ still appears. We get something like this:
$$\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right)^{-1} \to \left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right)^{-1}-x^{k}\right)^{-1} \to \left(\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right)^{-1}-x^{k}\right)^{-1}-6x^{k}\right)^{-1} \to \left(\left(\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{k}}\right)^{-1}-x^{k}\right)^{-1}-6x^{k}\right)^{-1}+\frac{10}{7}x^{k}\right)^{-1} \to \cdots$$
So these $a_n$ really do say something intrinsic about specifically $\sin(x)$. For finding $a_n$ in these cases the derivative process becomes a little bit difficult and it's better to use the limit definition of an asymptote, namely
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f_n(x) - a_n x^k = 0$$
I do not know if this pattern holds for more functions other than powers.


On a marginally related theme, in late August 1997 I spent a few days playing around with the graphs of $;y; = ;x\cdot \left(\sin \frac{1}{x}\right);$ AND $;y; = ;\left(\sin \frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right);$ AND $;y; = ;\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right) \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}\right);$ (and variations of these) with MAPLE, writing a 8-page analysis for some of my high school students in an honors level calculus course.

There are certainly formulas for the $a_n$ in terms of the series coefficients of $f_1(x)$: try the same experiment with $f_1(x) = (c_1 x+c_3x^3+c_5x^5+c_7x^7)^{-1}$, for example. But I don't see a general pattern.

What you were doing is generating continued fractions.
We start with a function $f(x)$ having expansion at $0$: $f(x)=\sum_{k=-N}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{k}$, then $f(x)$ is a $x$-adic number, then we use the map $x\mapsto 1/x$ to turn $f(x)$ into $f(1/x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{N}c_{-k} x^k$ (an expansion at $\infty$), we see that $f(1/x)$ is a base-$x$ real number. From here $f\equiv f(1/x)$. Let's define:

$\lfloor f\rfloor := \sum_{k=0}^{N}c_{-k}x^{k}$ (integer part of $f$), $\{f\}:=f-\lfloor f\rfloor$ (fractional part of $f$)
$H(f):=\{1/f\}$ (a Gauss map)

Now it is obvious that your experiment is repeatedly using $H(\cdot)$ to find partial denominators of $f$, meaning: $$f=a_0+\underset{i\geq1}{\operatorname{K}}\frac{1}{a_{i}} \tag{1}$$ $a_i$ can be functions of $x$, not just constants.
In conclusion:

I disclaim the convergence of $f$ in $(1)$, it's all depend on $f$ and $x$.
An abitrary $f$ most of the time will not produce visible pattern of $a_i$.
From well-known facts about continued fraction:
--Rational function always has finite continued fraction.
--Quadratic function always has periodic continued fraction and periodic continued fractions must be quadratic functions.

Note: Here, I mean quadratic function is such real $f(x)$ satisfying $f(x)^2+b(x)f(x)+c(x)=0$, where $b(x)$, $c(x)$ are rational functions.
Comment:
I'm not sure about the pattern of $a_n$ you found for $f(x)=\tan(x)$, but if it's true, it can be proved by (maybe) Gauss continued fraction or induction.
